# Does an irreducible $\mathbb CG$-module have a basis of the form $u,ug_1,\dots,ug_n$?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that $U$ is an irreducible $\mathbb CG$-module and $u\in U$. Let $\operatorname{span}(u_1,\dots,u_k)$ denotes the linear span of vectors $u_1,\dots,u_k\in U$.

I was thinking along these lines: there must exists some $g\in G$ such that $ug\notin\operatorname{span}(u)$, otherwise $\operatorname{span}(u)$ would be a nontrivial $\mathbb CG$-submodule. So I have two linearly independent vectors $u,ug\in U$.

Now $\operatorname{span}(u,ug)$ again is not closed under multiplication by group elements, otherwise it would be a nontrivial submodule. So I have some $(au+bug_1)g\notin \operatorname{span}(u,ug)$, which implies that either $ug$ or $ug_1g$ does not belong to $\operatorname{span}(u,ug)$.

I could continue in this way until I reach dimension of the $\mathbb CG$-module $U$.

However I have not seen this result in the introductory chapters of the book on representations I am studying. Which makes me think that either this result is not very useful, or that I have made a mistake somewhere. So is what I conjectured above true?

> - If $U$ is  irreducible $\mathbb CG$-module and $u\in U$, does there exists a basis for $U$ consisting of vectors of the form $u,ug_1,\dots,ug_n$, where $g_1,\dots,g_n\in G$?

Comment: Right actions, apparently. When you say ${\rm span}(u)$, do you mean $\bf C$-span or ${\bf C}G$-span? If the former, then how is ${\rm span}(u)$ necessarily a ${\bf C}G$-submodule at all, if the latter, then certainly $ug\in{\rm span}(u)$ by definition of span, no?

Comment: I meant $\mathbb C$-span.
The subspace $\operatorname{span}(u)$ is a $\mathbb CG$-submodule if and only if $ug\in\operatorname{span}(u)$ for each $g\in G$; which is what I was trying to use there.

Comment: Yes, it is true. This is called "spinning up a basis". It can be reasonably useful, but how do you choose the $g_i$? If you choose them carefully, you can often setup the matrix representations to have a nice form. However, often the $g_i$ are just chosen from a generating set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

If $u$ is any non-zero vector of an irreducible module $V$, then the subspace spanned by $X=\{gu:g\in G\}$ is a non-zero submodule. Irreducibility implies then that $X$ spans $V$ and therefore linear algebra tells you that a subset of $X$ is a basis $U$.

Comment: (That it be true does not mean that it is useful :-) )